# Get all Wikipedia meanings of a word in any language

Tags: python, api, wikipedia, disambiguation

I would like to get a list of all the Wikipedia meanings of a word. For example, for the word 'bar', the disambiguations are listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(disambiguation):

- Bar (establishment)
- Dessert bar
- Dive bar
- ...

Is there any way to access disambiguations of words from different languages from the Wikipedia API?

For English, I think the urls are mostly formatted as above (with disambiguation in the title). But for Spanish or other languages, the url for disambiguation page is different.

I've tried looking at the Category page which lists all the disambiguation pages (eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:All_article_disambiguation_pages&pagefrom=a), but it does not directly list all the disambiguations for the terms.

Comment: What do you mean? Which disambiguations that category doesn't list?

Comment: I'd like a programmatic way to get the list of disambiguations that you can see after clicking on a link in http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:All_article_disambiguation_pages&pagefrom=a. In Spanish, the corresponding page is: http://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Categor%C3%ADa:Wikipedia:Desambiguaci%C3%B3n&pagefrom=mactas.

Answer (score 1):

Most (all?) Wikipedia editions now have the [disambiguator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Disambiguator) extension installed, meaning that you can access all disambiguation pages from the API:

[`api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=DisambiguationPages`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=querypage&qppage=DisambiguationPages)

There is however a limit on WMF wikis like Wikipedia on the number of results you can retrieve this way, so if you need them all, you have to download a database dump and make the query agains that (in that case, you can read up a bit on the [page_props table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_props_table), and make a SQL query against that).

**A second approach** is to use WikiData, and query for all pages that is an [instance of (P31)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) [Wikimedia disambiguation page (Q4167410)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4167410).